# TypedValue.applyDimension producing wrong dimensions

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, text-size, android-screen

I use TypedValue.applyDimension and displayMetrix.scaledDensity to set text size in the TextView on my Xiaomi Redmi 5 plus and get surprizing results: text in the TextView is much larger than the one (same sp value) set in layout attribute. Here's my layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center|start"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:text="Some Text"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

And here is how I change text size:

```
TextView titleView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
titleView.setTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18, 
        getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
```

I also tried to use formula as follows:

```
(int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity * 18
```

On the emulator, I get the right text size, so I am not sure how to reproduce this. If someone manages to do that, please, leave comments for me and others to understand what is actually wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Check if you have your phone's fintsize is big in your phone's settings. That may increase the size of text in your textviews.

Comment: @NIKHIL It is small in the settings. Plus, if I set size in XML layout, it is displayed correctly

Answer (score 0):

So, I opend [TextView source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-mr0-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) and found out that TextView.setTextSize accepts sp, not px. So the answer is not to convert sp to px, but to use sp by default, or, if you need to support several size units, use *setTextSize(int unit, float size)*